# #include in @implementation in Xcode 6 / iOS 8 SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, include, parse-error

When porting one of my projects to Xcode 6 I noticed that, when using `#include` inside of `@implementation` blocks, the newest version now throw a `Parse Issue: Missing @end` build error. Previously this compiled fine.

Any idea if this is intended or if it can be disabled?

I am aware that having `#include`'s inside of `@implementations` is probably not good practice, nonetheless I sometimes use it if an include is tied directly to a specific method.

Comment: Don't do that, it doesn't exist and there's no point.

Comment: What is inside your's #include? My empty h-file doesn't cause any problems.

Comment: `#include` is basically copy pasting, so empty files won't make any errors but any obj-c header would fail.

Comment: @Jkmn I see. Interesting, though, that it worked fine in Xcode 5. But I guess I will just change my include's, thanks.